# Error while building flutter app for ios on codemagic - Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner`

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

When trying to build a flutter app codemagic is displaying the error below.

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install


Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

The app builds ok on android

I also noticed the following errors:

```
   [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_ml_vision":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_ml_vision (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_ml_vision/ios`)

    Specs satisfying the `firebase_ml_vision (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_ml_vision/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase you deployment target in your `Podfile` as stated in the plugin's documentation

> Versions 0.7.0+ use the latest ML Kit for Firebase version which
>   requires a minimum deployment target of 9.0. You can add the line
>   platform :ios, '9.0' in your iOS project Podfile.

Navigate to `ios/Podfile`(not `Podfile.lock`) and uncomment the second line by removing the `#` then try building again.

Comment: 10x, but I have no ios/Podfile, can you explain how to generate one?

Comment: run `flutter create ./` in your project root and it'll generate all missing files

Comment: `flutter create ./` didn't work, instead I started a build, ssh to the machine, did `flutter build ios` and pushed the files back to the repo

Comment: ohh yes. the should create the `Podfile`.
Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @JideGuru I am facing the same issue, can you share the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

If your CodeMagic build generates the Podfile you can try to update the `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file.

Replace all `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0;` lines by `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 9.0;`. You might see/need other version numbers .